# Can gang power go lower than 4%?

Tags: spiderman-3

In Spiderman 3 for the PS2, there are gangs that control parts of the city, and each gang controls a certain percentage of the city. When you do the "crime patrols", this percentage goes down and some power is returned to the police. I did crime patrols on every spot I could find for the "Dragon Tails" gang, but when I got them down to two spots and 4% power, I couldn't do the patrols any more.

At first I was able to go up to the informant, but hitting triangle would just do nothing. But next time I played the game the informants disappeared and were not at the spots that the two dots showed on the map.

Is this just a glitch or is 4% the lowest you can force a gang's power to go? If it is the lowest, does that mean that they will still attack other territories and try to increase their power, meaning I can never fully eliminate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been playing the game for a while longer now, and it turns out I needed the Dragon Tails gang for the next mission. Once the mission was over, I was able to do more crime patrols for their gang, and once I took out their last spot I got the message "Gang Defeated", and received ***A LOT*** of exp. Now their gang is at 0% and probably won't be ever coming back.